# How to install theme and syntax color scheme on Visual Studio 2019 (NOT VSCODE)?

Tags: themes, visual-studio-2019

I don't know how to install theme or syntax color scheme on Visual Studio 2019..
Can we at least do it or it is not possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select from multiple themes with the [Color Themes for Visual Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.ColorThemesforVisualStudio) extension.

Comment: Oh okay, so Visual Studio doesn't implements theme support officialy...

Comment: @TheoCerutti Well, an extension by the company designing the software itself seems official enough for me.